# When is using instanceof the right decision?

Tags: java, design-patterns

As I've always understood it, the main cases where an `instanceof` is appropriate are:

1. Implementing `Object.equals(Object)`.  So if I were writing a `List` class, and not extending `AbstractList` for whatever reason, I would implement `equals(o)` by first testing `o instanceof List`, and then comparing elements.
2. A significant (algorithmic?) optimization for a special case that does *not* change semantics, but only performance.  For example, `Collections.binarySearch` does an `instanceof RandomAccess` test, and uses a slightly different binary search for `RandomAccess` and non-`RandomAccess` lists.

I don't think `instanceof` represents a code smell in these two cases.  But are there any other cases where it is sensible to use `instanceof`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Legacy code or APIs outside of your control are a legitimate use-case for `instanceof`. (Even then I'd rather write an OO layer over it, but timing sometimes precludes a redesign like that.)

In particular, factories based on external class hierarchies seem a common usage.

Comment: Hmmmmm.  Any examples in mind?  I haven't encountered that need with any APIs I've played with.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Anything written in a non-OO fashion, for example, we had a third-party API where various FTP classes neither extended a common base class nor implemented an interface. In order to treat them the "same" our quick workaround was some trivial instanceof checks. Eventually we put a layer over the top. There are a ton of bad APIs in the world.

Comment: Ew.  I suppose I should be grateful for not having had to deal with any of those beasts.

Answer (score 7):

One way to answer your question would be to answer "when does a solid Java library use `instanceof`?"  If we assume [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is an example of a well designed Java library, we can look at where it uses `instanceof` to decide when it is acceptable to do.

If we extract the Guava source code jar and grep it, we see `instanceof` is mentioned 439 times, across 122 files:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/guava-13.0.1-sources
$ grep -R 'instanceof' | wc -l
439
$ grep -Rl 'instanceof' | wc -l
122
```

And looking at some of these cases we can see several patterns emerge:

- **To check for equality**

  This is the most common usage.  This is somewhat implementation specific, but assuming you do in fact want to measure equality based on the class/interface it extends/implements, you can use `instanceof` to ensure the object your working with is .  However this can potentially cause odd problems if a child class overrides `equals()` and doesn't respect the same `instanceof` requirements as the parent.  Examples everywhere, but an easy one is `Lists.equalsImpl()` which is used by `ImmutableList`.
- **To short-circuit unnecessary object construction**

  You can use `instanceof` to check if the passed in argument can be safely used or returned without further transforming it, for instance if it's already an instance of the desired class, or if we know it's immutable.  See examples in `CharMatcher.forPredicate()`, `Suppliers.memoize()`, `ImmutableList.copyOf()`, etc.
- **To access implementation-details without exposing different behavior**

  This can be seen all over the place in Guava, but notably in the static utility classes in the `com.google.common.collect` package, for instance in `Iterables.size()` where it calls `Collection.size()` if possible, and otherwise counts the number of items in the iterator in `O(n)` time.
- **To avoid calling `toString()`**

  I'm skeptical this merits being done in more than a very select few cases, but assuming you're sure you're doing the right thing, you can avoid needlessly converting `CharSequence` objects into `String`s with `instanceof`, like is done in `Joiner.toString(Object)`.
- **To do complex Exception handling**

  Obviously the "right" thing to do is use a `try/catch` block (though really, that's doing `instanceof` checks already), but sometimes you have more complex handling logic that merits using conditional blocks or passing processing off to a separate method, for instance pulling out causes or having implementation-specific processing.  An example can be found in `SimpleTimeLimiter.throwCause()`.

One thing that stands out looking at this behavior is nearly all of them are addressing problems *I should not be solving*.  They're useful in library code, e.g. in `Iterables`, but if I'm implementing this behavior, I should probably be asking myself if there aren't libraries or utilities that solve this for me.

In all cases, I would say that `instanceof` checks should only ever be used internally as an implementation detail - that is to say the caller of any method that relies on an `instanceof` check should not be able to (easily) tell that's what you did.  For instance, `ImmutableList.copyOf()` always returns an `ImmutableList`.  As an implementation detail it uses `instanceof` to avoid constructing new `ImmutableList`s, but that is not necessary to acceptably provide the expected behavior.

As an aside, it was amusing coming across your name, Louis, as I was digging through Guava's source code.  I swear I had no idea!

Comment: A utility library does not provide a good sampling of Java language usage. Eg, how many GoF design patterns does it use?

Comment: I used Guava as an example of a *good* codebase, not necessarily a representative one.  If there are other *good* reasons to use `instanceof` that I missed, I'll update the question.  At present, I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 4):

Your first case is an example where I would not use the `instanceof` operator, but see whether the classes are equal:

```
o != null && o.getClass() == this.getClass()
```

This will avoid that an instance of `A extends B` and `B` are considered equal

Other cases I can immediately think of but I am pretty sure more valid cases are available

- factory instances where you have for example a `canCreate` and `create` method which receive a general interface as parameter. Each of the factories can handle a specific implementation of the interface, so it would require an `instanceof`. Defining only the interface in the factory abstract class/interface allows for example to write a composite factory
- composite implementations (as illustrated in my first example)

Comment: But in the `List` case, you _want_ an instance of `B extends A` and `C extends A` to be considered equal.

Comment: Your first point is sometimes very important. However, there are applications where you want a subclass instance to be `equal` to a parent class instance. In that case, `instanceof` makes more sense than checking class identity. Also, `instanceof` is equivalent to your class identity check for final classes. I haven't benchmarked the two methods, but wouldn't be surprised if `instanceof` is a tiny bit faster in that case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But `instanceof` will fail in that case: `anA instanceof aB` will be `false`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion -- let's clear this up.  You want ArrayList.equals(LinkedList) to pass, so ArrayList.equals(o) tests if o instanceof List.  So I wouldn't be writing anA instanceof B, but someB instanceof A, where e.g. A is List, and B is ArrayList/LinkedList/whatever.

Comment: for use of `Class` comparison vs `instanceof` in `equals()`, I am more leaning towards using `instanceof`, because of Liskov substitution principle.  Comparing `class` is going to violate the principle  (Anyway, I think there is no rule of thumb: either way has their situation to be used)

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned, the "correct" uses of `instanceof` are rather limited. As far as I know, you have basically summed up the two main uses.

However you can generalize your statements a bit though as follows:

1. Type-checking before necessary casts.
2. Implementing special case scenarios that depend on very particular class instances