# WHY would one want to use the instanceof operator?

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm trying to answer this short answer question but I'm having a hard time understand what my instructor means by "why would we want to know this?". Any advice is greatly appreciated.

The question:

"What would be a use for the instanceof operator? Obviously it will designate if it is "an instance of" something--that is not the answer. The question is, why would we want to know that?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)

Comment: Uh, because we don't know what sort of object it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is using instanceof the right decision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957762/when-is-using-instanceof-the-right-decision)

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious and very common (mis)use of the `instanceof` operator is deciding on special handling for a subclass:

```
void recordPayment(Payment pmt) {
    // Do something common for all subclasses
    recordAmount(pmt.getAmount());
    // Do something special for the credit card subclasses
    if (pmt instanceof CreditCardPayment) {
        CreditCardPayment ccPmt = (CreditCardPayment)pmt;
        recordCreditCardNumber(ccPmt.getCardNumber());
    }
}
```

The use of `instanceof` often indicates with near certainty that your design is missing a function in the base class and an override in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to [downcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) a type, he may need instanceof operator. But that [usually indicates code smells](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/12/26/downcasting-is-a-code-smell/).

You may refer to this article: ["Prefer polymorphism over instanceof and downcasting"](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html).

**UPDATE**:

Seems the OP doesn't get the point of downcasting, let's explain in more detail.

Downcasting refines/narrows an object/value's **apparent type** to one of its **subtype**, such that it has the subtype's **semantics**.

This is useful when an object/value is declared as its *supertype*, but a caller needs some semantics or interfaces that are *specifically* in a subtype(i.e. those *absent* in the supertype). Only after the object/value passing the `instanceof`'s test and being downcasted to that subtype, can the caller takes use of its specific semantics or interfaces.

Comment: 1+ for mentioning "code smells" -- it's an operator you want to use very sparingly if at all.

Comment: @HotLicks why? Have you seen what I said is "**usually** smells"?

Comment: Saying "usually" is an indication that either you read a lot of really lousy code or you're a very poor judge of good code.  I'll let you decide which.

Comment: @HotLicks well, this article "Downcasting is a Code Smell"(http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/12/26/downcasting-is-a-code-smell/) even drops the "usually" word.

Comment: I've been programming for 40 years, and I never heard the term "code smell" until last week.  It's an invention of some new, self-declared "expert", not a term of the art.  I wouldn't trust the user of the term as far as I could throw him (which isn't very far with this bum shoulder).

Comment: @HotLicks That's just your personal opinion. Please have a look at wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: I don't see instanceof in that list.

Answer (score 1):

A very common place to need to use it is with JSON.  You can receive a JSON value that is a "nest" of map-like and array-like items, and the type of, say, a particular element of an array-like item may be either map-like or array-like, depending on numerous factors.

So `instanceof` is used to sort this out, or at least make sure that the expected type is present, rather than attempting the cast and blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need. I use almost all time the "instance of", like when I'm working on variables with "Object" type, and etc.

A simple thing is using objects with different types in an array. For example:

```
Object[] data = new Object[4];

data[0] = "String";
data[1] = 32;
data[2] = 32.64D;
data[3] = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then, you can check the contents:

```
if (data[0] instanceof String) {
  // Content at index '0' is a String
}
```

Comment: but the question is WHY. The question already states what it is used for but this is what I'm trying figure out: "The question is, why would we want to know that?"

Comment: @PatMoloney Because sometimes you have to have to write methods that work with something general (e.g. `Object`) but need to do something different if the object is something specific (e.g. `String`).  It's not always possible to know in advance what data type something will be.

Answer (score 0):

Take this situation, you have a `superclass`, reference which may refer to any of it derived class instance.
For example, There is a `abstract` class `Clothes`.Three classes `Shirt`, `Shorts` and `Jeans` are derived from it.

```
Clothes coolshirt=new Shirt();
Clothes coolshorts=new Shorts();
Clothes cooljeans=new Jeans();
Clothes gift=receiveGift();
if(gift instanceof Shirt)//Is the gift refers to a instance of Shirt
sendGratitude("Thanks for your new Shirt. It is really cool");
else if(gift instanceof Shorts)//Is the gift refers to a instance of Shorts
sendGratitude("Your shorts fits nice for me.Thank you.");
else if(gift instanceof Jeans)//Is the gift refers to a instance of Jeans
sendGratitude("In your Jeans I really look, Handsome, Very Thanks");
```