# Change if to switch statements

Tags: java

I am working in the Treasure Hunt Game Project for my java class, I got super confused when the professor asked me to do this **"Do not use instanceof, or break, except inside switch statements."**
currently inside the functions i am using if and for statements. 
Can i change it so i can get rid of intanceof?

In the button part I am using if(. . . intanceof. . . )
Can i do it with try and catch? instead of if? if so how?

**Treasure Game**

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TreasureBoardPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 10;

    // Instance variables
    private BoardButton[] button;   //used to add the button to the panel
    private TreasureGame game;      //used to make make the constructor for the TreasureBoardPanel

    //Costructor
    public TreasureBoardPanel(TreasureGame game) 
    {
        super();
        this.game = game;
        //setting the layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        //adding the buttons
        addButtons();
    }

    //Create and adding buttons to panel
    private void addButtons() 
    {
        this.button = new BoardButton[WIDTH * HEIGHT];

        //creating the random buttons
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < TreasureGame.NUM_TREASURES; i++) 
        {
            int index = random.nextInt(this.button.length);
            //Check if index is already a button
            while (this.button[index] != null)
                index = random.nextInt(this.button.length);
            this.button[index] = new TreasureButton();
        }

        // For all the buttons which are not TreasureButton i.e. null buttons
        // create BoardButton
        for (int i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) 
        {
            if (this.button[i] == null)
                this.button[i] = new BoardButton();
        }

        // Add all buttons to the panel and add action listener
        for (int i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) 
        {
            this.button[i].addActionListener(new ButtonListener(game));
            add(this.button[i]);
        }
    }

    //Display text from all treasures method
    public void displayAllTreasures() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) 
        {
            if (this.button[i] instanceof TreasureButton)

                this.button[i].setText(this.button[i].getDisplayText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood your professor's comments. The instanceof comment was unrelated to the switch/break comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good practice to often use instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894002/is-it-good-practice-to-often-use-instanceof)

Answer (score 1):

The point your professor was making wasn't to replace `if` with `switch`, but to avoid using `instanceof` in the first place and [use polymorphism instead](https://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html). Usually you can just add a method to the object's class which either handles the task itself or returns the information needed for the task, and override it in subclasses.

In this case, you could add a method to `BoardButton` called `isTreasure` that returns `false`, and have `TreasureButton` override it to return `true`. Then you can just call `btn.isTreasure()` instead of checking which class it is.