# What is a function for structs like Java's instanceof?

Tags: oop, object, struct, rust, instanceof

I'm making an OOP chat client in Rust. The module messages.rs creates and handles messages to other modules as structs: `SimpleMessage` and `ComplexMessage` structs:

```
//! # Messages

use time::SteadyTime;

/// Represents a simple text message
pub struct SimpleMessage<'a> {
    pub user: ...
    pub time: &'a SteadyTime<'a>,
    pub content: &'a str,
}

/// Represents attachments, like text or multimedia files.
pub struct ComplexMessage<'a> {
    pub user: ...
    pub time: &'a SteadyTime<'a>,
    //pub content: PENDING
}

impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a> { }
impl<'a> ComplexMessage<'a> { }

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn is_simple() {
        assert_eq!(&self.instance_of(), SimpleMessage);
    }

    #[test]
    fn is_complex() {
        assert_eq!(&self.instance_of(), ComplexMessage);
    }
}
```

I'm troubled finding a Java-like function such as `InstanceOf()` for structs, that would potentially work like:

```
&self.instance_of() -> str
```

This would be used to process a `ComplexMessage` different from a `SimpleMessage` in a GUI, adding a preview and download button for the `ComplexMessage`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need this, given Rust's compile time guarantees?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what types, fields, etc. are present in the code, nor can we see *why* you want to accomplish this goal or what code would require it. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Perhaps [How to match trait implementors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26126683/155423) will help

Comment: Your updated  code does not contain a definition for `User`; does it even need to have a user at all to show the problem? Most importantly, it doesn't show the code explaining why you *need* an `instanceof` check in the first place. It just shows that you want to call it.

Comment: Are you already aware that [using `instanceof` in Java is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894002/is-it-good-practice-to-often-use-instanceof)? Copying bad design from one language to the other is not usually an encouraged path.

Comment: Hard time writing a first-time question in StackOverflow haha, thank you @Shepmaster

Comment: *Hard time writing a first-time question* — I note from your profile that you are a CS student, so hopefully this unsolicited advice isn't unwelcomed: the feedback that we are providing you with is absolutely not limited to Stack Overflow. It will be pertinent to every part of your entire professional life. Reducing a problem to it's bare essentials ("create a MCVE"), evaluating *why* you are doing something, taking the time to format and frame your communication, etc. are all critical to success (in programming and likely most everything).

Comment: Any advice is more than welcomed @Shepmaster !  "crate" changed to "module", thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, if you try to port Java OOP idioms to Rust you are going to have a hard time. Rust programmers use completely different idioms and patterns, which are more suited to the design of the language.

That said, you can compare types using `std::any::TypeId`. A *similar* function to `instanceOf` can be implemented like this:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

trait InstanceOf
where
    Self: Any,
{
    fn instance_of<U: ?Sized + Any>(&self) -> bool {
        TypeId::of::<Self>() == TypeId::of::<U>()
    }
}

// implement this trait for every type that implements `Any` (which is most types)
impl<T: ?Sized + Any> InstanceOf for T {}
```

And use it like this:

```
let msg = ComplexMessage::new();

println!("msg is ComplexMessage: {}", msg.instance_of::<ComplexMessage>());
println!("msg is SimpleMessage: {}", msg.instance_of::<SimpleMessage>());
```

Outputs:

```
msg is ComplexMessage: true
msg is SimpleMessage: false
```

Note that Rust does not have a concept of type inheritance like Java does, so this will only tell you if it is exactly the same type.

---

A more Rusty approach to your problem, as DK commented below this answer, would be to use an `enum` to model the fact that you have two kinds of message. Rust `enum`s are nothing like Java `enum`s - they are just as powerful as `struct`s except they model the idea of alternatives, as opposed to aggregates. Here is one way you could implement this using the types you have and wrapping them up:

```
enum Message<'a> {
    Complex(ComplexMessage<'a>),
    Simple(SimpleMessage<'a>),
}
```

Whenever a function can only accept a `ComplexMessage` you can write the signature to reflect that:

```
fn send_multimedia(msg: ComplexMessage) { ... }
```

And whenever you can accept either type, use the `enum`:

```
fn get_msg_size(msg: Message) -> usize {
    match(msg) {
        Message::Complex(complex) => complex.content.len() + complex.file.size(),
        Message::Simple(simple) => simple.content.len(),
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your initial solution using `instance_of` work also if `msg` is a reference with a trait type, and if its value is some unknown trait implementation, either `SimpleMessage` or `ComplexMessage`? That is the essence of the Java `instanceof` operator, that the runtime type of the argument is tested. In your given example `msg` seems to have the non-reference type `ComplexMessage`. An `instanceof` operator which only works in that case is nothing like the one that is found in Java, and that should be clearly stated in the answer text.

Comment: I also thought about using a Struct-tuple, haven't given a thought for enums though, using them may be a more elegant (and much useful) solution, let me try it out, thanks DK. @Shepmaster

Comment: @Lii No it won't work in that situation. It's literally only going to match exact types.

Comment: Wouldn't [`Any::is`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.is) be a shorter implementation?

Comment: @Shepmaster Meh, it limits the types to be `Sized`. May not be a problem...

Comment: Thanks @PeterHall using enums it is the most elegant/practical solution.